# Spline coefficients relation to control points

Tags: c#, interpolation, curve-fitting, cubic-spline

To solve a fitting problem I'm working on I'd like to draw a cubic-spline through a set of sampled points. As end result for this particular problem I'd like to find the control points to do so.

For example: given the red points I would like to find the control points required to draw the black spline.

[image: Curve through points]

Now math isn't my strong suit but I found I required some sort of spline-interpolation to achieve this. Following the wiki article on spline interpolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) I find the spline coefficients a and b (for both the x and y part of the data).

Now my real question is how to relate these coeffiecients to a control point that I can use to reproduce the black line? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't you cheat, using a GraphicsPath? Use AddCurves and read the control points in the PathPoints array..

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks like this achieves exactly what I'd like to achieve. As such I really appreciate the response, however I would still like to know how to do this manually.

Comment: Sure; SO is however for coding problems. You may find more help in a Math community..